# Validating ASP.NET Server Controls

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I was looking for a simple way to control the data entered in a form , I came to this solution that I can use six different validation server controls that are available for ASP.NET:

RequiredFieldValidator

CompareValidator

RangeValidator

RegularExpressionValidator

CustomValidator

ValidationSummary

but in order to use these controls I have to include runat="server" in control tags and form tag.

the problem is when I want to specify a controller action in "action" attribute of "form" tag, It gives me the error:

Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs

Is there a way to use these controls and also call a controller action after submit?

here is my code:

```
<form name="register" action="<%: Url.Action("LogOn","Account") %>"  runat="server">          
    <div class="form_row">
        <label class="contact"><strong>Username:</strong></label>
        <asp:TextBox id="UserName" runat="server" type="text" class="contact_input"></asp:TextBox>
            &nbsp;
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator1"  
            runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required!" 
            ControlToValidate="UserName">
        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </div>  

    <div class="form_row">
        <label class="contact"><strong>Password:</strong></label>
        <input id = "Password" name = "Password" type="password" class="contact_input" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator1"  
            runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required!" 
            ControlToValidate="Password">
        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </div>                     

    <div class="form_row">
        <div class="terms">
            <input id = "RememberMe"  type="checkbox" name="terms" />
            Remember me
        </div>
    </div> 

    <div class="form_row">
        <input type="submit" class="register" value="login" />
    </div>   

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a very confused scenario. You describe an MVC project but you are using web form controls.

If you are using MVC, I would replace the .net controls with standard HTML controls and use data annotations for your validation. [See here for information](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx).

In MVC there should be no need to use `runat="server"` for anything.

Comment: thanks Digbyswift, yes I am using MVC and I was going in the wrong way , I will use data annotations , thanks for your help.